# Sed replace the last ", " before the 2000th character in a line

Tags: bash, sed

I'm executing a sql script with SQLPlus, but I have an error because some lines of the script are longer than 2000 characters.
So I would like to replace the last comma an space `'` before the 2000th character by `\n` on each line but I don't know how to do.

Does someone have an idea ?

Thanks for your help,

Steve

Comment: please show some sample input. You probably just need `set linesize 5000` (or some large number so your data will fit on one line.

Answer (score 2):

This sample should split very long lines at the first comma followed by a space to be at a position `>1900`. All lines shorter than 1900 characters will remain the same.

```
cat file.sql | sed -n 's/^\(.\{1900\}[^,]*,\) \(.*$\)/\1\n\2/gp; /^.\{1,1899\}$/p'
```

It does not split any lines into more than 2 [e.g. in case a line is, like, 5000 chars long], though. So, depending on how long you expect the longest lines to be, try running this multiple times in a row [with `file.sql` being overwritten by latest run's output, obviously...]

*EDIT:* **Also**, be aware of the special case of lines that are more than 1900 characters long, but don't have any commas coming up as of character #1900. These lines (e.g. "*`[...~1900 characters of...] comma, seperated, stuff [exceeding position 1900] followed by anything but expected seperator EOL`*") are just ignored entirely [*not even printed*] by the above solution. However, modification for those to be handled properly should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Using gawk 4.0, I did the test on 40 letter, you can replace with 2000 for your expect.

```
awk '{r=substr($0,41);s=substr($0,1,40);s=gensub(/,([^,]*)$/,"\n\\1","g",s);print s r}' file
```

The idea is, split the line into two strings: `s`(first 40 characters) `r` (the rest), then work on s to replace the last `,` to return `\n`

test file content:

```
hrsjdf,lkjajflkjafkljklfj,asdfadfk,afef=",/foa
jdf,lkjajflkjafkljklfj,asdfadfk,afef=",/foaasdfdf
```

Use fold command to help to understand your question.

```
$ fold -w40 < file
hrsjdf,lkjajflkjafkljklfj,asdfadfk,afef=
",/foa
jdf,lkjajflkjafkljklfj,asdfadfk,afef=",/
foaasdfdf
```

So the first line, we need add a return just before `afef=`, the second line should be added before /

Here is the result:

```
awk '{r=substr($0,41);s=substr($0,1,40);s=gensub(/,([^,]*)$/,"\n\\1","g",s);print s r}' file

hrsjdf,lkjajflkjafkljklfj,asdfadfk
afef=",/foa
jdf,lkjajflkjafkljklfj,asdfadfk,afef="
/foaasdfdf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ': beg
s/\(.\{250\}\)\{8\}/&\
/
t long
b
: long
s/^\(.*\), \([^,]*\)\(\n\)/\1\3\2/
P
s/.*\n//
b beg
' YourFile
```

Workaround for limitation by some SED with pattern buffer size limitation of 255 char (so 2000 char max is `\(.\{250\}\)\{8\}` )

Principe:

- take a raw line of max 2000 char by cutting the line by adding a `\n`. If not cutted, go out (and print content)
- find the last `,` and replace it by the ending `\n`
- print the first line of the buffer
- remove the first line
- restart the process (until line is under 2000 char)